# How to debug "You may need to add 'maginate.net' to ALLOWED_HOSTS"

Tags: python, django, nginx, web, gunicorn

I know this question is very similar to others, but I read all of them and still have not found a solution.

I registered maginate.net with Google Domains so the domain is active. When entering that domain it gives a DisallowedHost Exception. It says to put the domain name in ALLOWED_HOSTS, which I did, in the local_settings.py. And when I put the IP address `206.189.179.58`, the website runs perfectly. In my ALLOWED_HOST is a list:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['206.189.179.58', 'maginate.net', 'www.maginate.net']
```

And yes I have restarted the server many times. I don't know if my settings.py has anything to do with this, but leaving the ALLOWED_HOSTS blank or not still gives the error. I'm also following this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04) and doing exactly what it says.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is your `local settings.py` and `production settings.py` same?

Comment: I would suggest having a read of this: https://www.obeythetestinggoat.com/book/chapter_making_deployment_production_ready.html

Comment: No, they are not. The tutorial said keep settings.py the same, and overriding the important variables like SECRET_KEY and DATABASES along with ALLOWED_HOSTS to prevent the site to be hacked. @AstikAnand

Comment: That's fine and thats the way to go, now just make sure the code you are uploading to development contains the allowed_hosts. I think you are missing it in development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have updated the `settings.py` in only local system and you have not uploaded the updated settings code to production.

**I went through your url and error it is showing that.**

[image]

see your `ALLOWED_HOSTS` it only contains `'206.189.179.58'` and `'maginate.net'` and `'www.maginate.net'` is **not added** in `ALLOWED_HOSTS`.

Just try changing and uploading.

> Update after seeing code

You have put your `settings.py` and `local_settings.py` inside **portfolio** directory but it should be inside **portfolio/portfolio**

It will work fine.

Comment: Can you check again? I updated it and still the same error.

Comment: Which server you are using to host?

Comment: I am using digital ocean. Check this link please. https://github.com/mikeyyg96/portfolio/blob/master/settings.py

Comment: Ok, then ssh to your server, then use nano to edit the file and then use command `sudo service gunicorn restart` and also `sudo service nginx restart`  to restart server.

Comment: Your settings file is not getting updated as I can see that `DEBUG = False` in your code but still when I open it is going in `DEBUG` mode.

Comment: Yeah, that's why  I am confused. Why does it say my portfolio.settings only have 1 entry in ALLOWED_HOSTS, but I obviously have 3.

Comment: Just do ssh, use nano editor and change it na, it will start working.

Comment: I am using putty, I am connected to my server, and I have access to my django project. Both files have debug set to false and allowed host with the same entries.

Comment: Have you run `sudo service nginx restart` and `sudo service gunicorn restart` ???

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172373/discussion-between-astik-anand-and-user3152311).

Answer (score 0):

Taken from this [chapter](https://www.obeythetestinggoat.com/book/chapter_making_deployment_production_ready.html) from [Test-Driven Development with Python](https://www.obeythetestinggoat.com/), it looks like you could be having problems with your nginx configuration:

> **Fixing ALLOWED_HOSTS with Nginx: passing on the Host header**
>
> The problem turns out to be that, by default, Nginx strips out the
>   Host headers from requests it forwards, and it makes it "look like"
>   they came from localhost after all. We can tell it to forward on the
>   original host header by adding the `proxy_set_header` directive:
>
> server: /etc/nginx/sites-available/superlists-staging.ottg.eu
>
> ```
> server {
>      listen 80;
>      server_name superlists-staging.ottg.eu;
>
>      location /static {
>          alias /home/elspeth/sites/superlists-staging.ottg.eu/static;
>      }
>
>      location / {
>          proxy_pass http://unix:/tmp/superlists-stagng.ottg.eu.socket;
>          proxy_set_header Host $host;
>      } 
> }
> ```